# Usage of 的要 in 頭髮太長囉，該剪的要剪一剪了

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

I am having difficulty understanding how 的要 is being used in the second sentence:

> 頭髮太長囉
>   該剪的要剪一剪了

The first sentence makes sense: [Your] hair [is]  too long

However I don't understand at all how 的 and 要 are operating in the second one.  I was not able to find any information on it online (I may have searched for the wrong terms).

Comment: 該剪的 is a shorten device. The full version should be: 該剪的(頭髮/地方)要剪一剪了.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"的要" is not a term; "的" makes the phrase a noun, so "該(should)剪(cut)的" means "what should be cut". "要" means should/must/shall/will, so the whole sentence literally means "(you) should cut (the long hair) what should be cut".

Answer (score 2):

I like that. Must be at the barber's.

頭髮太長囉。
Your hair is very long.
該剪的要剪一剪了。
Trim the bits that need a trim.

該剪的 = the bits that need a trim

Answer (score 1):

The word "hair" is omitted on the second sentence. The complete sentence would be:

> 頭髮太長囉。
>   該剪的 (**頭髮**) 要剪一剪了。

該剪的 （頭髮） means "(the hair) that needs trimming" (here "的" works as "that")
要剪一剪了 "must trim"

So 該剪的 (**頭髮**) 要剪一剪了。 is "(the hair) that needs trimming must be trimmed"